How to customize AuthenticationManagers returned by JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver?
I'm interested in implementing custom logging, validation, and principal representation. OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration along with SecurityFilterChain allow for these customizations. However, I'm going for a multi user pool architecture. To support resolving the authenticator based on the token's issuer, configuring an AuthenticationManagerResolver seems like the way to go; however, it does not support any configuration beyond the list of trusted issuers. The validators, exception handlers, and converters appear to all be hard-coded. I need to either wrap many of the components of the JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver stack, or create my own resolver, which would essentially re-do most of the same work. Is there a way to provide customization of these behaviours that I'm missing somewhere?
I wrapped AuthenticationManagerResolver to handle the logging, and custom Principal representation, but additional JwtValidators are still eluding me.
